# can not install cocos2d

Tags: python, ubuntu, cocos2d-x, ubuntu-12.04

I tried to install **cocos2dx3.5** on **Ubuntu12.04**

```
$ cd /tmp && mkdir cocos2dxInstall
$ unzip cocos2d-x-3.5.zip -d /tmp/cocos2dxInstall
$ cd /tmp/cocos2dxInstall/cocos2d-x-3.5
$ ./download-deps.py
```

After I downloaded all the dependencies:

```
$ cd build && mkdir linux_build && cd linux_build
$ cmake ../..
$ make
```

waiting a very long time for them to compile, I ran:

```
$ cd ../..
$ cd tools/cocos2d-consle/bin
$ python install.py
```

Unfortunately, it raised an error:

```
Starting the installation for Cocos2D console
Downloading...
Installing...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "install.py", line 74, in <module>
    with TarFile.open(download_path) as tar:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1665, in open
    raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
 tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: What's the value of `download_path` and does that file exist?  Is it corrupt?

Comment: I scaned the install.py found `download_path, _= urllib.urlretrieve('https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-console/tarball/master')`.Then I inputed it in the brower tried to find the master branch,but there is nothing.But this is my download from this site`cocos2d-x.org/download`, should not be wrong.